# Does using the Click method in WPF break MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In a wpf interface with MVVM I have a close button and I'm using the button's Click method to close the application like so:

```
<Button Content="Close"  Click="CloseFunction"/>
```

My question is, am I breaking MVVM by doing this?

Comment: Why should it? It's absolutely fine, in general. MVVM is not about event handlers. It's about responsibilities. This means you have to look at the implementation details to decide if your code violates MVVM. For example, if your click handler handles data like reading or writing to a database or file, then your code will break MVVM as data handling is the responsibility of the model. If the handler modifies the view or accesses the view model, it doesn't break anything.

Comment: @BionicCode I thought I was supposed to use Command for this

Comment: Commands are not MVVM. They are a technique that is meant to help to let your view communicate with the view model. Like data binding. In terms of view communicating with view model they are both not mandatory. Data binding and events on the other hand are the only way the view model can anonymously or passively communicate with the view. However, events, commands, data binding, delegates, partial classes aka code-behind are just language level or framework level features. Design patterns are by definition not depending on languages.

Comment: All you have to do is to ensure that your dependencies don't violate MVVM. Active communication (or type referencing) is unidirectional: View --> View Model --> Model. The rest are design decisions. One can argue that the view model's API for the view is cleaner when it exposes commands instead of public methods (that the view can call from its handlers). Commands also help to reduce code-behind. Using event handlers or code-behind in general doesn't violate MVVM. MVVM is about application architecture and not about class design, frameworks, libraries or languages.

Comment: Trey, you can look into the Nuget package Xaml Behaviors which includes some good MVVM stuff. To answer your question, as posted we cannot deduce what happens in `CloseFunction`.  For example, if you desire to save state to a file, a more complex  operation like this would suggest the logic be moved to out of the view. `InvokeMethodAction` in the XAML Behaviors package allows you to create a binding to `DataContext` to call a method from a button click. It's a "cleaner" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does using the Click method in WPF break MVVM?

Not necessarily as long as you don't implement any *application logic* in the click event handler in the code-behind of the view.

For example, consider the following implementation that simply invokes a command of the view model from the event handler:

```
private void CloseFunction(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel vm = this.DataContext as ViewModel;
    if (vm != null)
        vm.SomeCommand?.Invoke(null);
}
```

It's as MVVM compliant as the following XAML markup which invokes the very same command from the very same view:

```
<Button Content="Close" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" />
```

MVVM is not about eliminating code from the views. It's mainly about separation of concerns.